# Const reference to a class member instead of a getter

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

Classic way to get a reference to class member or its value we use getters like `getValue()`. Could this be an alternative way? :

```
class A{
  ComplexClass value_;
public:
  //No need. ComplexClass const& getValue() const { return value_; }
  ComplexClass const& value = value_;   /// ???
}
```

Will this work? How do you like such syntax?

**UPD.**
This point is to make user code simpler. Personally I better like `auto x = a.value` than `auto x = a.getValue()`. *Of course this is a deal of taste.*

Will this still work nice if:

```
class A{
public:
  ComplexClass const& value = value_;
protected:
  ComplexClass value_;
}
```

I ask because I met some troubles with one compiler.

Comment: What is the point ? You just get extra code to correctly initialize the reference and you consume extra space in memory, just for the sake of the const access. Does not look good to me.

Comment: It works. Personally I don't like to give away any reference to encapsulated var.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen: Why are you calling out "correctly"? Are there aspects of C++ where you would generically expect gotten code to do something incorrect?

Comment: @KerrekSB good point, that was rethoric. It is still extra code tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main reasons to prefer member functions over data members is flexibility and maintainability. If you only ever wrote some code once, perfectly, and it would never be changed or reused, then you could certainly have public data members that users refer to directly.

The interesting question is what happens when your code doesn't meet these criteria, e.g. if it is going to evolve, and if other people start using it. Then once you have a public data member, you are forced to *always* have that data member. Details of your class layout are now part of your public contract. Simple refactorings like moving common parts into nested member objects are no longer private and break existing users.

Your proposed reference data member adds almost no benefit over a public data member (except for in very trivial cases), and unlike member functions, non-static data members affect the class layout. Class layout is another thing you will probably want to keep stable once you have users, so that old, compiled libraries can continue to be linked against new user code. Member functions are much easier to evolve while keeping the data layout unchanged.

There's a nice example in the standard library where such a mistake was made: `std::pair<T1, T2>` is specified to contain public data members `first` and `second`. That means that all user specializations must adhere to the same specification, and cannot easily employ things like base layout optimizations. Had `first` and `second` been specified as member functions, such optimizations could be applied trivially.

Comment: that was nice a real-life example from a standard library, +1 from me

Comment: Whilst it is true that flexibility and maintainability is one of the main reasons encapsulate data members in member functions I think there is another reason in this case which is to prevent mutation of the member variable. If OP doesn't care about encapsulation of the data member but does want to prevent callers from mutating it then a public data member would be a bad choice.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Sure, I took it as understood that a public data member would be *correct* from the point of view of the class design, and that we're only debating different choices among the correct ones.

Comment: @KerrekSB My point is that your statement "Your proposed reference data member adds almost no benefit over a public data member" is untrue. It has the benefit that it prevents that data member from being mutated.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: OK, I see, that's true. But to be clear, the OP's propsed reference *is also* a public data member.